# showing a list in column data grip angular 2

Tags: .net, angular, typescript

I'm trying to display a list of elements inside a column in a datagrid using angular 2. This is my code:

```
export class AlertData {
    constructor() {
        this.employmentList = new Array<KeyValue>();
        this.provincesList = new Array<KeyValue>();
        this.alertPeriodRefId = new KeyValue();
    }

    public alertId: number;
    public candidateRefId: number;
    public alertPeriodRefId: KeyValue;
    public creationDate: Date;

    public employmentList: KeyValue[];
    public provincesList: KeyValue[];
}



private createColumnDefs() {
    return [
        { headerName: "Puesto/s", field: "employmentList" },
        { headerName: "Ubicación/es", field:  "provincesList"},
        { headerName: "Periodicidad", field: "alertPeriodRefId.value"}
    ];
}
```

the fields employmentList and provincesList is a list of KeyValue elements and I'd like to display the values of those list in the column.

Could anybody help me please?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the PrimeNG components to draw similar UIs. You could find the data grid component here http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datagrid
This could act as your starting point.
I'd be happy to worth through a solution if you decide to use this component set.

Comment: Thanks but I don't need to change the component, the datagrid I'm using is ok. As a temporal solution I've added two more fields to the dto containing an string with the different employements/provinces and I display this string as the column field but this puts two much visualization logic in the service layer and I don't like it. I'd like to know if there is a better solution.